# Extract text inside span without class name using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract data from job search website using BeautifulSoup. I've been able to extract all of the data I need but the salary displayed.

The webpage is https://mx.indeed.com/jobs?q=operador&l=Ciudad%20de%20M%C3%A9xico

The problem I have is that the salary is inside a `<span>` without class name or title.

The sample html code looks like:

```
<div class="heading6 tapItem-gutter metadataContainer"><div class="metadata salary-snippet-container"><div aria-label="$12,000 al mes" class="salary-snippet"><span>$12,000 al mes</span></div></div></div>
```

I tried:

```
salary = card.find("div", {"class" : "salary-snippet"}).find("span").text
```

But I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Can anyone please explain how I can possible fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What happens?

The sample looks perfect but if you take a closer look, there is not an element of salary in all cards.

#### How to fix?

Just check if element is present bevor calling text on it:

```
salary = card.select_one('div.salary-snippet').text if card.select_one('div.salary-snippet') else None
```

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers ={
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'
}

r =requests.get('https://mx.indeed.com/trabajo?q=operador&l=Ciudad%20de%20M%C3%A9xico&vjk=970d586d3023d4d0')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

data = []

for card in soup.select('#mosaic-provider-jobcards a'):
    companyName = card.select_one('span.companyName').text if card.select_one('span.companyName') else None
    companyLocation = card.select_one('div.companyLocation').text if card.select_one('div.companyLocation') else None
    salary = card.select_one('div.salary-snippet').text if card.select_one('div.salary-snippet') else None
    
    data.append({
        'companyName':companyName,
        'companyLocation':companyLocation,
        'salary':salary
    })

data
```

#### Just wanna add jobs with salary?

```
data = []

for card in soup.select('#mosaic-provider-jobcards a'):
    companyName = card.select_one('span.companyName').text if card.select_one('span.companyName') else None
    companyLocation = card.select_one('div.companyLocation').text if card.select_one('div.companyLocation') else None
    salary = card.select_one('div.salary-snippet').text if card.select_one('div.salary-snippet') else None
    
    if salary:
        data.append({
            'companyName':companyName,
            'companyLocation':companyLocation,
            'salary':salary
        })

data
```